# How can I remove second workspace from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, workspaces, multiple-workstations

I set two workspace using super+1 and super+2 to separate lot of task.

But I notice when I constantly switching the app due to animation my eyes feel lot of pain.

So how can I remove second workspace without closing any Software/Files running on second workspace?

Comment: It seems bringing the windows on second workspace to 1st workspace will do.. Is not it what you want?

Comment: Are the worspapces static? I mean did you set them to have only two?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have 2 static workspaces..
ignore what ever windows running in both the workspaces..

run the below command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 1
```

[image]

[image]